# Restriction of a differentiable map $R^3\rightarrow R^3$ to a regular surface is also differentiable.

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, surfaces

This is again an excercise from Do Carmo's book.

Prove: if $f:R^3 \rightarrow R^3$ is a linear map and $S \subset R^3$ is a regular surface invariant under $L,$ i.e, $L(S)\subset S$, then the restriction $L|S$ is a differentiable map and $$dL_p(w)=L(w), p\in S,w\in T_p(S).$$

My attempt: Since any linear map on $R^3$ can be represented by a linear transformation matrix , it must be differentiable.  By definition I have to show that for any local parametrization of S say $(U,x)$, map defined by $x^{-1}\circ L \circ x:U\rightarrow U  $ is differentiable locally. Now, both $x$ and $L$ are differentiable , however , $x^{-1}$ is not necessarily differentiable.

Moreover, example 3, page 74 of Do Carmo's says : Let $S_1$ and $S_2$ be regular surfaces. Assume that $S_1\subset V \subset R^3$ where $V$ is an open subset of $R^3$, and that $\phi:V \rightarrow R^3$ is a differentiable map such that $\phi(S_1)\subset S_2$. Then the restriction $\phi|S_1: S_1\rightarrow S_2$ is a differentiable map.

This fact is left without proof, but I think it might be useful for the question.

Can anyone give me some help ? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if $x:U\subset \mathbb R^2\rightarrow S$ is a parametrization, then $x^{-1}: x(U) \rightarrow \mathbb R^2$ is differentiable: indeed, following the very definition of a differentiable map from a surface, $x$ is a parametrization of the open set $x(U)$ and since $x^{-1}\circ x$ is the identity map, it is differentiable.

Now, let $p$ be a point on the surface $S$, $x:U\subset \mathbb R^2\rightarrow S$ be a parametrization s.t. $x(0)=p$ and $y:V\subset \mathbb R^2\rightarrow S$ be another parametrization s.t. $L(p)=y(0)$.

To make it clear, let's say that $x(u,v)=(x_1(u,v),x_2(u,v),x_3(u,v))$ and $y^{-1}(x,y,z)=(\varphi_1(x,y,z),\varphi_2(x,y,z))$ then the map $L\circ x:U\rightarrow S$ is given by : $$L\circ x (u,v)=\begin{pmatrix} a&b&c\\d&e&f \\g&h&i\end{pmatrix}\begin{pmatrix} x_1(u,v) \\ x_2(u,v) \\ x_3(u,v) \end{pmatrix}$$

So $f(u,v)=y^{-1}\circ L \circ x(u,v)$ looks like $$f(u,v)=y^{-1}\circ L \circ x(u,v)=\\\ \begin{pmatrix}\varphi_1(ax_1(u,v)+bx_2(u,v)+cx_3(u,v),\cdots,gx_1(u,v)+hx_2(u,v)+ix_3(u,v)) \\ \varphi_2(gx_1(u,v)+hx_2(u,v)+ix_3(u,v),\cdots,gx_1(u,v)+hx_2(u,v)+ix_3(u,v))\end{pmatrix}$$
which is clearly differentiable.

Moreover, you can easily check using the chain rule that $$df_0=d(y^{-1})_{L(p)}\circ L \circ dx_0.$$
Roughly speaking, this map does : $$\mathbb R^2 \underset{dx}{\longrightarrow} T_pS \underset{L}{\longrightarrow} T_{L(p)}S\underset{dy^{-1}}{\longrightarrow} \mathbb R^2$$
which means that you send a vector of $\mathbb R^2$ onto $T_pS$ using the parametrization $x$ (it always gives you a good basis of the tangent space), then L acts and you read the information again using the second parametrization $y$ that takes the new vector onto $\mathbb R^2$.

So $L$ is nothing else but the derivative of $L:S\rightarrow S$ as a map between two surfaces.

In fact, this has to be expected because you might know that the derivative of a linear map between two vector spaces does not depend on the point and is equal to itself, so it has to be the same for surface or submanifold in general.

Comment: Hi @Bebop. Can you please clarify a bit more on how do you conclude that L is nothing else but the derivative of L ?

Comment: @user71346 Use the definition of differentiation